# MATLAB GUIDE GUI errors following function name change

Tags: matlab, refactoring, matlab-guide

I have renamed a `.fig` and associated `.m` file generated by MATLAB's GUIDE. Having done this, I receive a long list of error messages including the following (just a sample of them shown below):

```
Undefined function or variable 'my_gui'.

Error in @(hObject,eventdata)my_gui('edit34_CreateFcn',hObject,eventdata,guidata(hObject))


Undefined function or variable 'my_gui'.

Error in @(hObject,eventdata)my_gui('edit33_CreateFcn',hObject,eventdata,guidata(hObject))


Undefined function or variable 'my_gui'.

Error in @(hObject,eventdata)my_gui('edit32_CreateFcn',hObject,eventdata,guidata(hObject))
```

These errors all seem to relate to individual items on my GUI, such as buttons, text boxes etc.

The function and `.fig` file *used to* be called `my_gui.m` and `my_gui.fig`. However, I have sinced changed the name to `my_new_gui.m` and `my_new_gui.fig` (I've simplified the actual names for the purposes of this question).

So, the obvious solution is to go into the `.m` file and replace all instances of `my_gui` with `my_new_gui`. However, I've done this, and the same error message appears. I have no idea where MATLAB is the reading text `my_gui` from, since it doesn't exist in any of my code... Any help would be appreciated!

**Edit** I've discovered that these old references are written in the callbacks for each item on the GUI, which I can change by opening the Property Inspector for each individual item. However, I have a *lot* of items. If anyone can offer a solution to quickly edit these using a text editor, rather than clicking each individual one, I'd appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Renaming MATLAB GUI should be done using `Save As...` rather than manually changing the file names. Change the file names back to the original names and change the name using `Save As...` option in GUIDE. This should automatically rename everything.